# Фонетический разбор слова "заяц" - (з а й' а ц) или (з а й' и ц)?

Tags: фонетика

Фонетический разбор слова "заяц" - (з а й' а ц)  или  (з а й' и ц) ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Вариант - [заj'ьц].Этот вариант мне кажется правильным.

В заударном слоге гласный [ь] краткий, он находится после мягкого согласного [j'].

2. Вариант - [з`ай’иц]. Такой способ разбора есть [здесь](https://frazbor.ru/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%86). Мне он кажется неточным, так как звук [и] слишком выражен.

Comment: Екатерина, но ведь [j] и [й] не произносятся в этом слове. Почему вы используете значки для них в своих транскрипциях?

Comment: Разбор этого слова не так прост, как кажется. Тысячи раз произносишь слово, желая услышать или не услышать этот [j']. И всё равно чуть-чуть, но  слышишь! В школе мы принимали разбор и без [j'] - [зáиц]. Ваш вариант, конечно, тоже рассматривала, смущает только, что мягкиий редуцированный идёт после "а".

Comment: То, что вы чуть-чуть слышите, и есть [ь] — это редуцированный гласный (непонятно, почему вы называете его мягким, ведь это термин для согласных звуков). [j] — щелевой звук, и он очень хорошо слышен. Да и встречается только перед ударным гласным. Более того, у этих звуков просто различная формантная структура и длительность.

Comment: "Мягкий и твёрдый" редуцированный - это гласные звуки ь и ъ, так с университетских времён мы их называем, чтобы легко различать. Дети плохо усваивают [еръ] и [ерь], путают. Вы правы, это ненаучно). Учту.

Comment: Основной вопрос не к вашим терминам, а к вашим транскрипциям все же...

Comment: Вы уверены, что в транскрипции может быть сочетание звуков [аь]?

Comment: Конечно может быть!.. Тут скорее вопрос в том, почему оно не может быть.

Answer (score -1):

Оба варианта неверны.

Слово *заяц* произносится как [зáьц], где [ь] краткий (редуцированный) гласный.

Если вам нужно записать по-школьному, думаю, сойдет и [зáиц].

Никакого [j] в этом слове нет — он встречается перед ударными гласными, например: *пиявка* [п’иjáфкъ]. ([ъ] — другой редуцированный, встречающийся после твердых согласных.)

Звук, обозначаемый иногда как [й] («и неслоговой»), также отсутствует в этом слове. Его можно встретить, например, в слове *добрый* [дóбръй].

Comment: § 53. На месте буквы я (и буквы а после [ч] и [щ]) в безударных окончаниях произносится гласный [ъ]: ср. ка́пля, ды́ня (произносится [ка́пл❜ъ], [бы́н❜ъ]); мо́ря, поля́, о́куня, пла́ча — род. п. ед. ч. (произносится [мо́р❜ъ], [по́л❜ъ], [о́кун❜ъ], [пла́чъ]); пе́рья, сту́лья, су́чья - им. п, мн. ч. (произносится [пе́р❜йъ], [сту́л❜йъ], [су́чйъ]), ка́плям, ка́плями, ка́плях (произносится [ка́пл❜ъм], [ка́пл❜ъми], [ка́пл❜ъх]); ро́щам, ро́щами, ро́щах (произносится [ро́щъм], [ро́щъми], [ро́щъх]); и́мя, вре́мя, пла́мя, стре́мя

Comment: (произносится [и́м❜ъ], [вре́м❜ъ], [пла́м❜ъ], [стре́м❜ъ]); ви́дя, зна́я, пла́ча (произносится [ви́д❜ъ], [зна́йъ], [пла́чъ]); зла́я, друга́я (произносится [зла́йъ], [друга́йъ]); ста́рая, до́брая (произносится [ста́ръъйъ], [до́бръйъ]); бара́нья, пти́чья, вра́жья (произносится [ба́ран❜йъ], [пти́чйъ], [вра́жйъ]); сего́дня (произносится [сиво́д❜н❜ъ]).

Comment: @Ajgy простите, к чему вы привели этот набор слов?

Comment: К тому, что ваш разбор неверен.

Comment: @Ajgy не думаю, что набор слов без указания источника и приведения каких-либо фонетических аргументов имеет отношение к моему "разбору".